# Query on Latest records out of multiple records in a Laravel Relation

Tags: laravel

I have two table `users` and `users_logs` .

The `users_logs` table is linked with `users` by `user_id`.

The `users_logs` table may have multiple entries against different users, like 100 records may have against one `user_id`.

I want to fetch all users from `users` table and then want to check if the last (the latest entry) in `users_logs` table has `created_at` smaller than the certain date, if yes, then fetch that records else not.

i have also created a hasMany relation in `users` table.

```
public function users_logs_details(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UsersLog', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

The code i tried is

```
$users = User::with(['users_logs_details'])
            ->whereHas('users_logs_details', function($query) use ($certainDate) {
                return $query->where('created_at', '<', $certainDate);
            })->get();
```

But i am not getting any result because, this query is checking in all records in `users_logs` table, but i want to check only the latest record.

Please help, i would be highly thankful.

Comment: Can you try: `$users = User::with(['users_logs_details'])
            ->whereHas('users_logs_details', function($query) use ($certainDate) {
                return $query->where('created_at', '<', $certainDate)->latest()->take(1);
            })->get();`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert : No , it is not working, it is giving all records if any of the record date matches with certainDate , i want to check only the latest record and return it only if the condition matches else no reocrd for that user_id.

Comment: it should not - in what format is your `$certainDate` ?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert : it has timestamp format, same as created_at.

Comment: oooh, remove the `with(['users_logs_details'])`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert : i have applied your code and checked multiple times, the problem is that, it is first checking the condition on entire rows, then selecting the latest record and returning it, if condition matches in any of the records.

i want to match condition only on the latest records out of multiple entries.
Thanks

Comment: You are better off with a join function I think

Comment: @ChristopheHubert : can you help me with that, i have less idea about joins in laravel